# Letting exceptions throw for reasons of processing speed?

Tags: regex, vb.net, performance, exception, character-encoding

I am not sure, this could be a question that is more related to opinion.

Lets say I have a very long list of strings (>100 million) that need to be parsed. 0.01% of these strings contain illegal UNICODE characters (such as ASCI-characters).
When it comes to processing speed, would it be considered bad practice of using a Regex expression (for replacing or removing illegal characters) only when an Exception is thrown? (e.g. 'Exception occurred: hexadecimal value 0x02 is an invalid character')

I could compare speed for both options, but I am more concerned about program stability, readability and adaptability of code etc.

I am using VB.Net.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Catching Exceptions and correcting them immediatly is usually an excellent way to go! I'm not sure for that exact topic, but I think you're good to go.

Comment: If (1) you can be sure that you are not missing errors for which an exception will **not** be thrown, (2) the occurrence is as exceptional as you think and (3) you can actually determine what to do when an exception is thrown and (4) it makes a significant performance difference that you need, this would look like a good design decision. As with all important design decisions make sure you look at the trade offs and document it well.

Comment: Great, thanks for both of your comments! This helps, I think I will add Regex replace Expression to the Exception handling block (and feel good about it).

Comment: For my money, I fall back to an exception as part of normal workflow only as a last resort or if there is no choice given the library I'm using. It's also good to consider that you'll want to handle additional exceptions from the exception block now that you're doing something important within that block. Usually better to check your pre/post conditions within the Try instead of relying on the exception. More of a coding issue than a performance issue, though.